# Custom multi-auth guard logging & routing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6

I'm developing a Laravel 6 app with 4 different users(with a different table for each). For this, I am using multi auth guard and created my first guard following this tutorial online (https://pusher.com/tutorials/multiple-authentication-guards-laravel).

Here is my **custom guard "student"**

```
    'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
    'student' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'students',
    ],
],
```

**And Providers**

```
    'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'students' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Student::class,
    ],
],
```

I have a custom login controller using a custom auth guard named 'student'

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use Student;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('destroy');
        $this->middleware('student')->except('destroy');
    }
    public function studentLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email'   => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|min:5'
        ]);

        if (Auth::guard('student')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->get('remember'))) {

            return redirect()->intended('admin/home')->with('smessage', 'Logged in successfully...!');
        }
        return back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
    }...
    }
```

Now, Whenever I try to log in, It seems like I am logged in and redirected to the URL defined in the middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php but this error pops up "Trying to get property of non-object" which is from the common header template where no data of logged user are available on `auth()->user()`.

If I use `'middleware'=>'auth:student'`, I can access the route as student and have the logged user data via `auth()->user()`. same for admin using `'middleware'=>'auth'` but passing both `auth` and `auth:student` as an array I can't get the logged user data via `auth()->user()` for both user.

**Here are my routes:**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('/login', 'LoginController@create')->name('login');
Route::post('login', 'LoginController@store');
Route::get('/login/student', 'LoginController@create')->name('studentlogin');
Route::post('/login/student', 'LoginController@studentLogin');

Route::get('/logout', 'LoginController@destroy')->name('logout'); 

Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin', 'namespace' => 'Dashboard', 'middleware'=> 'auth' ], function () {

    Route::get('home', 'DashboardController@display')->name('admin.home');

    Route::get('users', 'UserlistController@display')->name('admin.userlist');
    Route::post('users', 'UserlistController@store')->name('admin.create');
    Route::delete('users/{id}', 'UserlistController@destroy')->name('admin.deleteuser');

});

Route::group(['prefix'=>'student', 'namespace' => 'Students', 'middleware'=> 'auth:student' ], function () {
    Route::get('all', 'StudentsController@display')->name('student.all');
    Route::delete('all/{id}', 'StudentsController@destroy')->name('student.delete');
    Route::post('all', 'StudentsController@store')->name('student.store');
});
```

Couldn't find any solutions from other related topics on StackOverflow. Please do correct me if I have any mistakes somewhere or let me know if you want to inspect any other files for the code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try a video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NuyouEHghac&list=PLe30vg_FG4OTO7KbQ6TByyY99AiSw1MDS

Comment: Can you please post the full route definition for the route you're trying to access after authentication? Notice also that you're redirecting users that log in as student  to `admin/home`, not to route that's defined in `RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware.

Comment: @arun I've gone through the mentioned video as well, I believe I've already covered all the steps mentioned.

Comment: @matteo-meil though the redirection is set to 'admin/home' from loginController I am still redirected to what I've defined in the redirectIfAutnenticated.php i.e. "student/all". Are there any mistakes? P.S. I've added my route definition to the question as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any data on `auth()->user()` because you're querying the default guard which is `web`.

If you want to retrieve the logged user through `student` guard, you have to do `auth()->guard('student')->user();`

Also remember to pass everytime your guard to `auth` and middlewares that uses `auth`.

I.e.: if you need to make some routes restricted only to authenticated users you will need to do:

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:student'], function() {
    // Your restricted routes
})
```

Omitting `:student` will use the default `web` guard as always

Note that if you need to restrict your routes to a **group** of users belonging to different guards you can pass those guards to `auth`:

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:web,student'], function() {
    // Your restricted routes
}];
```

In this way Laravel will check for both `web` and `student` guards and will automatically set the one that belongs to the authenticated user. You will also be able to retrieve your user only by doing `auth()->user()` forgetting to pass the right guard

Comment: Okay, I've added the middleware  ['middleware' => 'auth:student']  for the route group student. Whenever I apply this middleware it works for that route i.e.  i receive the data of logged user on both auth()->user()  and  auth()->guard('student')->user();  on the student related routes

Great! But why can't I access routes or routes group where I haven't applied any middleware (because they are public pages which can be accessed by any user)?

Comment: Because of `'middleware'=> 'auth'` in routes definition (check your routes definition). As I wrote in my answer, those routes will use the default `web` guard. If you don't specify any middleware you won't have any problem to access that route but if you assign the wrong one you won't be able to access it

Comment: Thanks for the clarification but:
1. I don't get the data of the logged user via `auth()->user()` on routes with no middleware defined
2. I tried adding `'middleware'=> ['auth', 'auth:student']` but can't even access the route from both admin & student user. Am I doing something wrong again?

Comment: In routes with no middleware you have to use `auth()->guard('student')->user()`, as I wrote in the answer. In routes with `middleware'=> ['auth', 'auth:student']` you have to remove `auth` and leave only `auth:student`. Note that middlewares are executed in the order you write them. You should read carefully [middlewares docs](https://laravel.com/docs/middleware)

Comment: There will be few others users and their middlewares using the same template where `auth()->user()` will be used, so I can't just use `auth()->guard('student')->user()`. Same with the middleware in routes, using only `auth:student` will allow access for students only while I want it to be accessed by multiple users or all users in some cases. What are the best approach to do this?

Comment: Regarding the middleware you can pass a list of guards in this way: `auth:web,student,other_guard` to make the route available to authenticated users from all those guards. Then, inside your route you can easily access your authenticated user via `auth()->user()` because Laravel, under the hoods, checks against all specified guards and then sets globally the right one using `shouldUse($guard)` method. Take a look at `Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate@authenticate` to have an idea of what Laravel does

Comment: Oh! you mean I can pass a list of guards in this way `'middleware'=> ['auth:web,student']` so that I can access the route from users who belongs to both web & student guard. Perfect! Can you also update your main answer with the possibilities to add multiple guards within a middleware, So that I can mark your answer as most helpful? Thanks!

Comment: Edited my answer, check it now